# C# windows service crashes due to ntdll.dll issue

Tags: multithreading, windows-services

My windows service keep crashing and stopped in between. When I traced the eventviewer logs, I got the following information. What can be the reason? It's a multi threaded service application.

```
Faulting application name: xxxxxxx.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x581b6c80
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7c8f9
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000c40f2
Faulting process id: 0x25b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d238d4c9bd8587
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Application\Application.exe 
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 201eb89f-a4c8-11e6-89ad-64006a6629b4
```

Exception code `0xc0000374` means you're facing heap corruption.

The most common causes for this kind of error are buffer overruns, when one thread tries to read something and another thread has removed data in the meanwhile. This shouldn't happen in managed code as far as I can tell.

Comment: have any clue about which lines of code are generating this error?

Comment: When the number of threads increase, usually the crashing happens and the service application stops in between. Not at a specific line of code.